# Similar triangles and circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> We have $k(O;r$). $AB$ is a chord and $t_1$ and $t_2$ are tangents to the circle at points $A$ and $B$, respectively. I should show that the distance from every point lying on the circle to $AB$ is equal to the product of the distances from the point to $t_1$ and $t_2$. 
>   [image]

So, if we succeed in showing $\dfrac{PQ}{PM}=\dfrac{PN}{PQ}$, the problem is solved. We can try to show $\triangle MPQ \sim \triangle QPN$, but I don't see how to. I am trying to use the fact that $AQPM, QBNP$ and $MPNK$ are cyclic quadrilaterals, but it seems useless at the end. Can you help me?

Comment: Does it help that $\angle MAQ \cong \angle NBQ$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

$$\angle PMQ = \angle PAQ = \angle PAB = \angle PBN = \angle PQN.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why $\angle PAB=\angle PBN$?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova the angles subtend the same arc of the circle, one as a tangent.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\angle KAB = \angle KBA$ due to the tangent points $A$ and $B$. Then, the two cyclic quadrilaterals $AMPQ$ and $BNPQ$ are similar. Thus,

$$\dfrac{PQ}{PM}=\dfrac{PN}{PQ}$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It's nice but I'd like to solve the problem only by using similar triangles.